# ora-03113 end-of-file on communication channel on creation of database

Tags: oracle-9i

I'm trying to create an oracle database in my local machine via Database Configuration Assistant tool. At the last step, when I lunch the creation, I'm having this issue of  :
`ORA-03113 end-of-file communication channel`

I've looked for some documentation, but I still can't debug the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: platform? 9i is very old .... What is in the alertlog file?

Comment: @ik_zelf the logfile is normally in {oracle_base}\admin\database_name\alert_{database_name}.log But I can't find it I think the tool hasn't created it yet

Comment: Did you check the certification matrix? 9i is very old and if you are installing on a recent windows version, that could be the problem. Also check http://docs.oracle.com/html/B10163_01/toc.htm

Comment: @ik_zelf http://docs.oracle.com/html/B10924_01/toc.htm#1021953 no problem for support